# Dagger 2 not generate DaggerAppComponent

Tags: java, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger

I've found the same problem here several times. But no matter what I do, the DaggerAppComponent class is not generated. I follow the tutorial here: 
[https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-android-dagger-2-10-2-11-butterknife-mvp-part-1-eb0f6b970fd](https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c)

and here: 
https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-using-livedata-rxjava-and-new-dagger-android-injection-639837b1eb6c

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My Gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def daggerVersion = 2.13

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mjana.testappjava"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // RxJava 2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'

    // Dagger 2
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"//
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
}
```

Application file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;
import dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector;
import dagger.android.HasActivityInjector;

/**
 * Created by janam on 29.11.2017.
 */

public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent // Not generated

    }


    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Gradle Console:

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

Comment: Dagger's component generation happens during compilation, and if there's any sort of syntax error--or any sort of error from Dagger regarding invalid or missing bindings or modules--Dagger won't generate the component. That said, there's no single reason that the component won't generate; we'd need to see your compiler output to know the specific problem. Please edit it into the question.

Comment: I added the Gradle Console output. I do not see anything about the Dagger. Is it possible to turn on a more detailed output somewhere? I'm primarily a C # developer. Android studio is quite new to me.

Comment: Thanks! And your Module and AppComponent.java? I presume it resembles [this one](https://github.com/jshvarts/DaggerAndroidMVVM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/daggerandroidmvvm/di/AppComponent.java).